# Function to detect if there's any touch occurring on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm trying to create a simple function, similar to the `touchesBegan`, that detects if there's any touch occurring on the screen.

I've hit a brick wall trying it out myself because I'm not comfortable with UITouch class, but I really need some self made function, outside the `touchesBegan` default one.

I was trying to do something like this 'pseudo-code/swift'

```
func isTouchingTheScreen() -> Bool {
   let someTouchHandleConstant: uitouch ???
   if imTouchingTheScreen {
       return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
}
```

Do you have any hints?

**PS**: I know that code doesn't work, don't call that out, it was just to give you some 'image' of what I was trying to do (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The idea

You can simply keep track of every touch **begun**, **ended** or **cancelled** by the user.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var activeTouches = Set<UITouch>()

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        activeTouches.unionInPlace(touches)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        activeTouches.subtractInPlace(touches)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touches = touches {
            activeTouches.subtractInPlace(touches)
        }
    }

    var isTouchingTheScreen: Bool { return !activeTouches.isEmpty }
}
```

### Keeping `activeTouches` updated

As you can see I am keeping updated the `activeTouches` Set.

Every time a touch does **begin** I add it to `activeTouches`. And every time a touch does **end** or is **cancelled** I remove it from `activeTouches`.

### The `isTouchingTheScreen` computed variable

This allows me to define the `isTouchingTheScreen` computed property that simply returns `true` when the `Set` contains some element.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **UITapGestureRecognizer** as below:

```
var tapGesture :UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func didMoveToNode() {
    // Add UITapGestureRecognizer to view
    self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.touchedView(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
func touchedView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("view touched")
}
```

Comment: Well, as I wrote I needed a function that's not the touchesBegan default one.

Comment: you can add UITapGesture to detect touch.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
// global var
var tapGesture :UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func didMoveToView() {
    // Add tap gesture recognizer to view
    self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handleTap(_:)))
    self.tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("GameScene tap")
        if sender.state == .Ended {
             var positionInScene: CGPoint = sender.locationInView(sender.view)
             positionInScene = self.scene!.convertPointFromView(positionInScene)
             let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
             if touchedNode.name != "myHero" {
                 print("The SKSpriteNode myHero was tapped")
             }
        }
}
```

You can find more details in Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer).

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't remembered that at all. I think that will work. I'll give you feedback later on when I implement those functions :)